# Why is it not getting into the if condition?

Tags: java

I have this code.

```
public String Login(String email, String password) {
    String mode = "";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userdb, passdb);
        Statement select = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM doit WHERE DoitEmail='" + email + "' AND DoitPassword='" + password + "'");

        if (result.first()) {
            mode = "doit";
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    return mode;
}
```

What seems to be the problem why is it not returning the value for `mode` inside the `if` statement.

In other words, why is it not executing the `if` statement block, when I debug, it directly goes to `return mode` without setting new value for `mode`?

UPDATE: Im using the new code... (it has the single quote at the end..)

UPDATE2: Problem solved,,,

Comment: ***NEVER*** have an empty catch block like this: `catch(SQLException) {}` unless you like driving your car with your eyes closed. If so, remind me never to drive with you or use your code.

Comment: Because it's throwing a SQLException.

Comment: Also see [SQL Injection Prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) so that someone can't hack your password check by supplying the email `hacked@example.com' OR 1--@gmail.com`

Comment: What if my email really is '; DROP ALL DATABASES; @gmail.com' ?

Comment: @Paul, that'd have to be `"'; DROP ALL DATABASES; SELECT '"@gmail.com` to pass an RFC 5322 validator.

Comment: Must be Little Bobby Tables mom's email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing quote, change:

```
DoitPassword='"+password+""
```

to:

```
DoitPassword='"+password+"'"
```

Further, like was already commented above, it's bad practice to catch exceptions without (at least) printing the error to log.

And last, I'd like to introduce you to one of my good friends: *[Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)*

Comment: I tried this -> ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM doit WHERE DoitEmail='"+email+"' AND DoitPassword='"+password+"'");   it doesnt work,, it still doesnt go to the next statements... : [

Comment: @IvanMatala save the select query into a string variable and print it. If it looks fine - try to manually run it directly in the DB and see how many results you're getting. In addition to that, like already mentioned: add error printing inside the catch block.

Comment: sorry, i mistyped the code,, it already had the missing single quote at the password

Comment: ,, how do we add error printing, can you provide sample code. tnx

Comment: Try: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 1):

It is not going into the `if` condition because you the `ResultSet`'s cursor is not at the first row.
The `result.first()` method returns `true` only when the `ResultSet`'s cursor is pointing at the first row.
Either try calling `result.isFirst()` or call `result.next()` before calling `result.first()`.
Hope this helps!

**Unrelated**
You may try [MySQL JDBC Utilities](https://bitbucket.org/s1lent_warrior/mysql-jdbc-utilities) API for easy Java-MySQL tasks.